# compiler failed to apply explicit conversion to an expression used as a condition

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion, explicit-conversion

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class Sales{
  public:
    Sales(int i = 0):i(i){}
    explicit operator int(){ return i; }
  private:
    int i;
};

int main(){
  Sales s(5);
  if(s == 4) cout << "s == 4" << endl;
  else cout << "s != 4" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

In c++ primer(5th), it says:

> compiler will apply an explicit conversion to an
>   expression used as a condition

But in this case, there is no such conversion.
When I delete `explicit`, the code then works fine.

However, when I change
  `explicit operator int(){ return i; }` to
  `explicit operator bool(){ return i != 0; }`,

and change `if(s == 4)` to `if(s)` respectively, then the code works fine.

Looks like the convesion rule is a little bit confusing, can anybody explain this in more detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Among [implicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion), since C++11, the explicit user-defined conversion function will be considered for [contextual conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions); which happens in the following contexts and when type `bool` is expected. For `int`, it's not applied.

> In the following five contexts, the type `bool` is expected and the
>   implicit conversion sequence is built if the declaration bool t(e); is
>   well-formed. that is, the explicit user-defined conversion function
>   such as explicit T::operator bool() const; is considered. Such
>   expression e is said to be contextually convertible to bool.
>
> ```
> controlling expression of if, while, for;
> the logical operators !, && and ||;
> the conditional operator ?:;
> static_assert;
> noexcept.
> ```

Comment: So, only `operator bool` can be conversed? Others like `int` can not? But I think cpp primer(5th) don't describe this limitation.

Comment: @YuanWen Yes. It only happens when the type `bool` is expected.

Comment: So, you believe c++ primer(5th) is not clear enough in this topic?

Comment: @YuanWen It might want to express that in the  contextual conversion (i.e. used as a condition) an explicit conversion to `bool` will be applied, but not precise enough at technical perspective. (But might be enough for initial understanding as a book; and I believe it might be explained more somewhere like appendix. :) )